# How to provision a Hadoop ecosystem cluster with OpenShift?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, openshift, hortonworks-data-platform

We are searching a viable way for provisioning a Hadoop ecosystem cluster with OpenShift (based on Docker). We look to build up a cluster using the services of the Hadoop ecosystem, i.e. HDFS, YARN, Spark, Hive, HBase, ZooKeeper etc.

My team has been using Hortonworks HDP for on-premise hardware but will now switch into a OpenShift-based infrastructure. Hortonworks Cloudbreak seems not to be suitable for OpenShift-based infrastructures. I have found [this](https://de.hortonworks.com/blog/openshift-v3-kubernetes-docker-hadoop-yarn/) article that describes the integration of YARN into OpenShift but it seems like there are no further information available.

What is the easiest way to provision a Hadoop ecosystem cluster on OpenShift? Manually adding all the services feels error-prone and hard to administer. I have stumbled upon the Docker images of these separate services, but it is not comparable to the automated provisioning you get with a platform like Hortonworks HDP. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Openstack within Openshift, [Sahara allows provisioning of Openstack Hadoop clusters](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/5/html/Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/chap-OpenStack_Sahara_Installation.html)

Alternatively, [Cloudbreak is Hortonwork's tool](https://hortonworks.com/open-source/cloudbreak) for provisioning container based cloud deployments

Both provides Ambari, allowing you the same interface for cluster administration as HDP.

---

FWIW, I personally don't find the reason for putting Hadoop in containers. Your datanodes are locked to specific disks. There's no improvement in running several smaller ResourceManagers on a single host. Plus, for YARN, you'd be running containers within containers. And for the namenode, you must have a replicated Fsimage + Editlog because the container could be placed on any system

Comment: 1) Openstack on Openshift seems like a weird thing to do; is it not? Can you elaborate on how this will work? 2) We have seen Cloudbreak too. Unfortunately it is only for Openstack clusters too.

Comment: I edited the question after I already linked to Openstack Sahara... As far as I know, Openshift is just a pool of resources running Kubernetes. You can install any container solutions within it. Openshift runs containers within this environment. See https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-on-openstack-delivering-applications-better-together/

Comment: You might also be interested in http://b4mad.net/datenbrei/openshift/hadoop-hdfs/

Comment: Thanks for your input! What do you think about hosting "naked" RHEL docker containers on top of Openshift and then "manually" installing Ambari on one of the containers and let Ambari provision the services to all other containerized nodes? It sounds like a reasonable solution to me; do you see any pitfalls?

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, but the pitfall is that you're required in that deployment scenario to run an SSH server within each container as that's how Ambari communicates with the external systems for provisioning. Some people argue a container never needs SSH as you can `docker exec` into a shell... Also, the agents must be configured to a static address for the Ambari server for heartbeats. I don't know how well those packets will travel in the network if the server container is restarted and deployed elsewhere.

Comment: It's also not clear how you monitor host information from the agent container. Plus, Ambari will attempt to install all Hadoop services within the agent container, as far as I know. It has no access to the Docker daemon to provision other containers for each service.